# Handle incrementation of value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using ASP.Net MVC and have following code.

```
@
{
   int id=0;
}
@foreach(var item in (<IEnumerable>Problem)ViewBag.Problems
{
     <div>
            <h2>  <a href="#" id=@id onclick="IncrementVisits(this)" > @item.Subject </a> </h2>
             @id++             -----Special Line 1
             <a href="#"> Visit(<span id="@id">@item.Visits</span>) </a> 
             <hr />
     </div>
        <br />
        id++;                   ------Specila Line 2   

}
```

Problem is that in Special Lines 1 and 2( which i have given these name just for understanding ) i want to increment value in `id` but don't want to show in div. How to avoid with this that value in `id` should not be displayed in div and increment should also be done. Please help.

Comment: Do you know about the preincrement operator?

Comment: Have you tried @(id++)

Comment: Actually I think that explicit expression will still output the value in the view. Try a code block. @{id++}

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you should use a code block:

```
@{
    id++;
}
```

Opposite to expressions (i.e. `@id++`), code blocks don't produce any default output.